# How to determine file type in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Is there anything like `file` in shell for lisp to determine file type? If not, how do you determine file tpye?

In most case `pathname-type` is good enough, but sometimes you may run into some files doesn't have been correct named.

Comment: What about using `uiop:run-program` to call the shell command `file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality of `file` is available in `libmagic`:

> *As of version 4.00 of the Ian Darwin/Christos Zoulas version of file, the functionality of file is incorporated into a libmagic library that is accessible via C (and C-compatible) linking;[7][8] file is implemented using that library.*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)#Libmagic_library)

And there is a binding for Common Lisp.

I had to install `libmagic-dev` on my system, and then:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :magicffi)
... 
(:MAGICFFI)

CL-USER> (magicffi:pathname-mime #P"/bin/ls")
"application/x-sharedlib; charset=binary"
```

See [`MAGICFFI`](https://common-lisp.net/project/magicffi/).

Comment: Looks good, However, it looks like that `magicffi:pathname-mime` doesn't exist in `magicffi`. The example given at [github](https://github.com/dochang/magicffi) looks like this:`with-open-magic (magic '(:mime-type :symlink))
    (magic-load magic)
    (magic-file magic #P"magicffi.asd"))`

Comment: @C-Entropy There are probably different ways to use the API, but the above example Works on my machine (TM)

Comment: Maybe we are using different version? Where do you get the package and what is the version? Mine comes from [github](https://github.com/dochang/magicffi) and should be last updated  on Aug 14, 2017

Comment: I have it from quicklisp, magicffi-20200925-git, you're welcome !